# Is it ok for PhD to come from same school as BA?

Tags: phd, tenure-track

If my ultimate goal is to obtain a tenured teaching position, is it more desirable to get a PhD from a different university than the one where I obtained my BA? What are the possible pros and cons?

The original university has a large philosophy department, which is also a factor for me.

Comment: I'd say that this fact will be washed away by your much more important graduate and postgraduate performance. They'll look for independent work (don't publish all your work with the same narrow group of people) and it's amount.

Comment: When you are nearing the completion of your BA, ask the faculty you know at your institution whether it would be better for you to continue there or to apply elsewhere.   They (and you at that time) should know the answer better than we do here.

Comment: The main things that will matter are that the PhD institution is a very good one, and that you do very good work. After that, also having gotten your bachelor's degree from a very good university can make a small positive difference (though it's largely drowned out by the first two things I mentioned), regardless of whether it's the same or a different place. I'd be astonished if anyone thinks there's anything negative about staying at the same school. Lastly, all my degrees (bachelor's, master's and phd) are from the same place, and I'm a tenured professor.

Comment: @DanRomik *I'd be astonished if anyone thinks there's anything negative about staying at the same school.*  I've certainly heard it suggested that this is a bad idea for a student's intellectual development, and I think many US departments incline against taking a lot of their own undergrads, especially in recent years.  But I don't think that this is really the OP's question.

Comment: @BenWebster okay, I guess there are all kinds of weird beliefs floating out there that don't make any sense to me, so I'll just have to concede that some people see things that way. On such matters I recommend following Steve Jobs's wise advice: "_Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma - which is living with the results of other people's thinking. Don't let the noise of other's opinions drown out your own inner voice. And most important, have the courage to follow your heart and intuition._"

Answer (score 5):

Many people refer to PhD programs accepting students from their BA programs as "**academic incest**." (The same term is used for hiring PhD students from the same program into the tenure track).  The reasons why doctoral programs generally don't want to commit academic incest are:

- As with physical inbreeding, academic incest reduces the intellectual gene pool. You've already studied under a singular group of faculty for your BA, go to another program for your PhD to widen your intellectual horizons.
- As with physical inbreeding, if your program is known for academic incest, it dissuades possible future candidates from applying -- or at minimum, feeling that you prioritize your 'own' over others.

There are clear reasons why a **program** might not want to be known for incestuous tendencies. However, the question is whether this hurts a **candidate**. Here, the risk/benefit analysis is a bit more murky.

**Pros:** If your program is indeed the best in X-Studies, why not remain at the best?

**Cons:** There is a risk that you might be seen as parochial -- that you only really know the intellectual currents at your single alma mater. To be honest, I'm not sure how significant a risk this is in terms of *jobs* although I would for the reasons of scholarly diversity above, still suggest that students *not* apply to their own PhD programs.

---

<sup>Fine print: Note that claims of the negative aspects of academic incest are much more pronounced (and pernicious) in the humanities and social sciences; and are much less common in the lab sciences. If there's only one university lab in the USA that does the type of gene splicing you want to do and you're continuing a project that you've done as an undergraduate, it'd be silly to think of going elsewhere.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

My BS and PhD universities are the same, and I have a good life. Although, I've never applied for a tenure track position.

Comment: My situation is much the same. I did apply to tenure track jobs, but my failure to get offers had nothing to do with my undergrad institution and everything to do with my state of preparation at the time.

Comment: My BS and PhD are from the same institution and I've had a reasonably successful career despite being told that I was making a mistake by getting my PhD from the same institution where I got my BS degree.  I think it would have been better for my career if I'd gone elsewhere for the PhD, but as it happened, the best program I got into was at the institution where I got my BS degree.

Comment: I had already line up research work with my eventual PhD supervisor, so I just kept going. I didn't apply to TT positions because my (more or less) current job fell in my lap with 6 months to go on my PhD.

Answer (score 1):

My BS and MD will be coming from different organizations. I know tenured professors who have all their degrees from one school and other professors that went all over the place. The advice that I have been given over time is to focus on ideas that interest you, people who inspire you and institutions that provide enough resources for you to pursue your intellectual curiosity. In the end, academia is about publishing work that interests you and pushes science forward. If you are good enough to do that than you will find tenure somewhere.

Comment: "If you are good enough to do that than you will find tenure somewhere" -- is way too optimistic a statement given the current job market.